# What is the best way to preprocess fields with Display Suite

Tags: 7, commerce, theming, display-suite

I'm using Display Suite with Drupal Commerce, and I need to pre-process some fields in my product display.  I need to change some values based on some conditions, and need to wrap a few fields in some markup.  Should I write a hook to pre-process and change the values, and use a template to wrap the fields in markup?  If so, which template file would I use, because DS comes with a few templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize your field at theme level by using [TEMPLATE_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) function at `template.php`

You can get get some field value by `node` object or by fetching `field` values itself. You can do something like this to get fields value by node object --

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) { //Replace your theme name MYTHEME here.
  if ($node = menu_get_object()){
    if($node->type == 'PRODUCT_DISPLAY'){//Use your product display name here.
      $vars['node'] = $node;
      $product_id = $node->FIELD_PRODUCT_REFERENCE[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['product_id'];//Use your product ref field name here.
      $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
      $manufacturer = $product->FIELD_PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];//Use your field name of product type here.
      $final_body_label = "Description by ".$manufacturer;

      //Set body label for node from here itself.
      $node->content['body']['#label_display'] = $final_body_label;

      //Or set a variable to use it further. 
      $$vars['manufacturer_description'] = $final_body_label;
  }
}
```

Further you can use your default template for node or page if it fulfils what you want or you can make separate `TPL` for fields too, which will be named like `field--field_image.tpl.php`, where `field_image` is field name of your content or product.

You will get default `field.tpl` in $`base_path/modules/field/theme`.

Comment: I created a preprocess-field.inc file (I'm using Omega), and added the themename_preprocess_field() function, but it's not being called.

Comment: @vintorg - I don't know about omega. Why didn't you put your pre-process function in template.php file ?

Comment: Omega suggests pre-process functions are stored in their own file.  You would put themename_preprocess_page(), for example, in a file called preprocess-page.inc.

Comment: @vintorg Can you try it once with template.php ?

Comment: Actually, this is a known issue:  https://drupal.org/node/1536070

Comment: I moved it to template.php and it is called.  NOTE TO OMEGA USERS - don't include the '_alpha_' part of the theme, as you would in your preprocess-*.inc files.